# Please explain the output this regex (starts with a positive lookahead)

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=[1-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]*[05]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("101");
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.start()+":"+ m.end()+ m.group());
}
```

---

**Output-**----- >> `0:210`

Please let me know why I am getting output of `m.group()` as `10` here.
As far as I understand `m.group()` should return nothing because `[05]` matches to nothing.

Comment: Why do you think so? You do not set the `??` quantifier after `[05]`. It must match something.

Answer (score 2):

Your Pattern, `(?=[1-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]*[05]` consists of 2 parts:

```
(?=[1-9][0-9]{2})
```

and

```
[0-9]*[05]
```

The first part is a **zero-width positive lookahead** which searches for a number of length 3, and the first can not be 0. This matches your `101`.
The second part searches for any amount of numbers and then a 0 or a 5. This matches the first 2 characters of `101`, thus the result is `10`.

See [Java - Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.

Comment: @Neftas The first part matches a number with a **total length** of 3.

Answer (score 0):

What your Regex is looking for is:

- **[1-9]**:
  match a single character present in the list below
  1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
- **[0-9]{2}**:
  match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- **[0-9]***:
  match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- **[05]**:
  match a single character present in the list below
  05 a single character in the list 05 literally

for the String "101" this nacht the first 2 chars **10**1,
so you are printing.out:

```
System.out.println(**m.start()**+":"+ **m.end()**+ m.group());
```

> where **m.start()** returns the start index of the previous match(char at
>   0). **where m.end()** returns the offset after the last character matched.
>   and where **m.group()** returns the input subsequence matched by the previous
>   match.

Comment: How is that an answer to why it matches `"101"`?

Comment: Sir sorry to say I am still not getting why m.group() return 10

Comment: After lookaround expression,[0-9]* matches 101 and then it try to match [05] which does not match so why m.group(0) returning 10. If I assume that 101 fails then it backtrackes to 10 and then it again try to match [05] where it again fails and similar for further backtracking. Please explain the output

Comment: Because 10 is the string found by the matched by the regex. @user3907559

Comment: @user3907559 you are almost there. It will backtrack one more time until `[0-9]*` matches only `1`, and after that `[05]` will match `0`, so it outputs `10`.

Comment: Just so you know there are some pretty powerful regex tools online. I personally use regex101 which highlights the capture groups and lets you set up unit tests. Here's your regex for example: https://regex101.com/r/dM8tW0/1

Answer (score 0):

That regex was meant to match a number that's a multiple of 5 and greater than or equal to 100, but it's useless without anchors.  It should be:

```
^(?=[1-9][0-9]{2}$)[0-9]*[05]$
```

The anchors ensure that both the lookahead and the main part are examining the whole of the string.  But the task doesn't require a lookahead anyway; this works just fine:

```
^[1-9][0-9][05]$
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AlanMoore states, there has to be an alignment.

Assertions are a self contained entity, all they have to do is *Pass*
to advance to the next construct.

Lets see what `(?=[1-9][0-9]{2})` matches;

`111`1111110666
`222`2222222222222225666
`333`33333333333333333333330666

So far so good, on to the next construct.

Lets see what `[0-9]*[05]` matches.
What ever this matches is the final answer.

`1111111110`666
`2222222222222222225`666
`33333333333333333333333330`666

What to learn is that to get a cohesive answer, assertions have to be crafted to
coincide with constructs that come after them.

Here is an example of a *constraint* that could be applied
*after the assertion*.

The assertion state's it needs three digits and the first digit must be >= 1.
The constructs after the assertion state it can be *any number of digit's*,
as long as it ends with a 0 or 5.

This last part is distressing since it will match only the `5`00000

So for sure, you need at least three digits.
That can be done like this:

`[0-9]{2,}[05]`

This says two things

1. There must be at least three digits, but can be more
2. It must end with a  0 or 5.

That's it, put it all together, its:

`(?=[1-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]{2,}[05]`

Of course, this can be condensed to;

`[1-9][0-9]+[05]`